# Why Does Windows 10 Fail to System.Diagnostics.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe")?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I noticed that some of the newer Windows 10 exe applications don't start using System.Diagnostics.Start() method.  For Example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe")?
```

However Older Windows exe's will start:

```
System.Diagnostics.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")?
```

and others such as Calc.exe in Windows 10 are lost and mixed up in "metro random string id land" and have a way to provide a real file system path to execute them from System.Diagnostics.Start().

But, Specifically, I want to know why "StikyNot.exe" doesn't work from Start() and how to launch this application from c#?  For, its just says that the file is missing, but clearly it is there when you type "dir C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe" from cmd.exe.

(Also, I'm using Windows 10 straight from the install CD-ROM without installing any updates.)

Comment: What is "StikyNot.exe"? Are you trying to launch Sticky Notes?

Comment: Sticky Notes on my OS (1703) is a modern app, there is no `StikyNot.exe` in the said location anymore. In your case, you might need to compile your app as x64, otherwise, the app might be actually searching for C:\Windows\SysWoW64\StikyNot.exe due to WOW file redirection.

Comment: Yes, Sticky Notes.  I noticed that after Fall 2017 Creators update is applied, afters a clean install of windows 10 from CDROM, the StikyNot.exe is no longer located under C:\Windows\System32\StikyNot.exe.  But, instead is locked up as a Metro App with its exe path hidden. (Maybe its why they are hiding them because you can't start them as a process in C# with System.Diagnostics.Start() method, neither can you right click on the property under the start menu for Sticky Note to find the path to the Exe via properties click menu, like normal Windows Application.